# How to get not full collection using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I study Hibernate and now have such structure:

**Class Person:**

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  ...

  @OneToMany(...)
  private List<Task> tasks;

  ...

}
```

**Class Task:**

```
@Entity
public class Task {

  ...

  @Column(...)
  private boolean isCompleted;

  @ManyToOne(...)
  private Person person;

  ...

}
```

**My question is:** How can I get Person object with only tasks which are completed?
I tried this HQL query using Hibernate Session:

`SELECT person FROM Person person JOIN Task task WIH task.completed = true`

but of course I get just persons that have completed tasks but every list cotains the rest of them also. I've heard something about **Criteria** abilities but it's deprecated. So how can I do it via HQL or some new API? I use Hibernate 5. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to select tasks that are completed with their persons and not persons with completed tasks. It is better to use the Many side of the association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`@OneToMany(...)
@Where(clause = "is_completed = true")`

Please note that you have to write sql in the @Where clause value, since this will be applied during native sql generation.

From documentation-

> - Where clause to add to the element Entity or target entity of a collection
> - The clause is written in SQL